# How to populate a text box using dlookup from two combo boxes after update

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to populate the textbox `txtprice` using the `cboprod` and `cboweight` as criteria.

Price is currency, product is text and size is number.

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub form_load()
  Me.txtqty = ""

  Dim price As Currency
  price = DLookup([price], "invent", "[product] = & cboprod &" And [size] = txtweight)

  Me.txtprice.Value = price
End Sub

Private Sub cboprod_AfterUpdate()
  DoCmd.Requery
End Sub

Private Sub cboprod_AfterUpdate()
  DoCmd.Requery
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

First some remarks:

- I guess your DLookup never worked well:

  - `[price]` must be provided as a string: `"[price]"`
  - Your parameters for the condition must be concatenated into the string. You've had them as part of the string.
  - Because product is a string it's condition value must be encapsulated in `'`s.
  - The conditions syntax was spoiled up a bit...
- Also it's not recommended to name fields/objects like reserved names: `size` is such a word.
- Always try to provide the property you want to use explicitely. In this case it is `.Value`. It works without, but can cause trouble depending on which variable type it is assigned to. Then it could be assigned as the object you reference it.
- Add an `Option Explicit` in the top of each module. This prevents usage of undeclared variables and so makes debugging easier.

I would encapsulate the functionality in a sub procedure and call it where/when needed.

This should be what you want:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub form_load()
  RefreshPrice
End Sub

Private Sub cboprod_AfterUpdate()
  RefreshPrice
End Sub

Private Sub cboprod_AfterUpdate()
  RefreshPrice
End Sub

Private Sub RefreshPrice()
  txtprice.Value = DLookup("[price]", "invent", "[product] = '" & cboprod.Value & "' And [size] = " & txtweight.Value)
End Sub
```

Comment: Am now getting an error. "Run-time error '424': Object required." The debugger is highlighting the line with the txt.price.Value = Dlookup....

Comment: Add an `Option Explicit` in the module (see my edits above). This will show up usage of undeclared variables. I guess one or more of your controls (`txtprice`, `cboprod`, `txtweight`) is misspelled, so this causes error 424.

Comment: Its not producing any results